# Are there any Virtual Machine programs that can detect the actual video card

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualization, gpu

I was wondering if anyone knew of any virtualization programs that would allow a VM to detect the actual hardware video card, and not an emulated/simulated one. I ask this because I would like to see about the possibility of running a VM that would be accessible through VPN that I could use video card intensive apps on remotely.

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VirtualBox and VMWare Workstation can, *if* you have IOMMU Virtualization (aka VT-x, Directed I/O, AMD-Vi) enabled on your CPU, chipset, and OS. (And there are lots of niggling little caveats depending on the primary OS you run.) VMWare ESX/i and Xen Server have the same requirement on the server side. Searching for IOMMU Virtualization should get your information on whether it's even feasible to try it yet.

Comment: Thanks, this solves the general question, I'll do further research from here on how to go forward.